# TimePicker SetHour Method

Tags: android

I obtain a warning in Android Studio upon using the setCurrentHour Method (as below), that it has been deprecated.

```
timePicker.setCurrentHour(hour);
```

Meanwhile, upon using the setHour Method (as hereafter), I obtain a warning stating that the "Call requires API level 23" while the current minimum is lower.

```
timePicker.setHour(hour);
```

Is there a Support Library that I could use for Backward Compatibility, avoiding thus any warnings?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is already a support library for this, but this is what I've done when I was dealing with these methods:

Java:

```java
    private void setTime(int hour, int minute) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
          mTimePicker.setHour(hour);
          mTimePicker.setMinute(minute);
        } else {
          mTimePicker.setCurrentHour(hour);
          mTimePicker.setCurrentMinute(minute);
        }
    }
```

And in Kotlin:

```kotlin
    private fun setTime(hours: Int, minutes: Int) {
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            time_picker.hour = hours
            time_picker.minute = minutes
        } else {
            time_picker.currentHour = hours
            time_picker.currentMinute = minutes
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.